# Objective-C unallocated pointer

Tags: objective-c, pointers, null

i'm confusing about nil in objective-C, cause apple said that it's ok to send a message to a nil object.

so suppose this code :

```
Foo * myFoo;
[myFoo doSomeStuff];
```

in Xcode this doesn't crash so why? does unallocated pointer in objective-C is the same as nil.

Thanks.

Comment: is `myFoo` a global variable? Those are always initialized to zero.

Comment: myFoo is not a global variable.

Comment: @Gallois: There is a difference between an unallocated pointer and an uninitialized pointer. You have an uninitialized pointer, and the behavior is undefined when the pointer is allocated on the stack (local variable) and not initilized, as described in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there's a difference between `nil` and `random garbage`. You see, this line:

```
Foo * myFoo;
```

does not make any guarantee for the value of `myFoo` if you don't explicitly set one. Try for yourself:

```
Foo* myFoo;
printf("%x\n", myFoo);
```

It is likely that it won't print `0`; instead, it will print the last thing that happened to be at that memory location. (It *might* be zero. But it very well may not be.)

Local variables have an undefined value before you assign them one by yourself. The Objective-C runtime will let calls to `nil` work, but `nil` is strictly defined to be zero: therefore, you have to initialize your variables to `nil` to use this feature (otherwise, you're likely to get a segmentation fault, because messaging a random address isn't good for your program).

This will always "work" (by "work" I mean not crash):

```
Foo* myFoo = nil;
[myFoo whatever];
```

---

Here is an example program that, with my machine, consistently doesn't have zeroed pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct random_stuff
{
    int stuff[60];
};

struct random_stuff scramble()
{
    int filler = 0xdeadbeef;
    struct random_stuff foo;

    memset_pattern4(&foo.stuff, &filler, sizeof foo);
    return foo;
}

void print()
{
    void* pointer[30];
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        printf("%p\n", pointer[i]);
}

int main()
{
    scramble();
    print();
}
```

Comment: @Gallois In a very simple program (just the main method), it is very possible that it does print 0. I'll update with an example where it doesn't print `0`.

Comment: I understand thanks, but my problem is that this doesn't crash. It seems that Objective-C treats unallocated pointer as the same as nil!!!

Comment: @Gallois Oh, I got your question the wrong way. Well, there's a chance that unassigned pointers get the `nil` value, but it really is chance. If you do this: `Foo* myFoo = (Foo*)0xdeadbeef;` you'll see that sending a message to anywhere won't work.

Comment: Thanks, i understand better now :).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the variable. An instance variable, global variable or static variable will be initialized to nil unless you initialize it to something else. An ordinary local variable is not initialized to any defined value, and messaging a variable like that will usually crash. Note that that's *usually*, not *always* — when you're talking about undefined behavior, just about anything is possible, including crashes, messages going to the wrong objects, or behavior that seems correct most of the time and fails at random.